# Where can I find Drum Scores / Sheet Music?

Tags: composition, sheet-music, drums, transcription

What Websites offer quality Drum Scores /Sheet Music (not Tabs)?

Comment: This is kinda off-topic to ask for resources. We're supposed to *be* a resource. But I'm not gonna raise a ruckus, because drum sheet music is something I've searched for without success in the past. The worry about these questions is that the links die and the whole page becomes just so much more broken internet noise. So if you guys are posting links:: Say something about it, your personal take, is there *good internet experience* on the other side of that click?; Remember, it's a promise to keep the link updated if the page moves around or something. ...Technique questions have less baggage

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requesting a list of resources.

Answer (score 7):

*I'm not a Drummer, but I would highly recommend investing in a copy of [Guitar Pro](http://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php).  Most of the songs I've downloaded for guitar pro have the transcribers really putting a ton of effort into transcriptions of songs.*

It allows you to follow along, speed up, slow down, loop etc, and the Real Sound Engine means that the drums actually sound realistic.  A quick search for [song name] Guitar pro pretty much always yields Success.

The software doesn't cost much, and once you have it sheet music is free everywhere (that I've found!)

**Here's an example of what the drum scoring looks like**

[image: Here's an example of what the drum scoring looks like]

Like I say I'm not a Drummer, but I am interested in studying some real Percussion and Drum Sheet music.  From Mike Portnoy to Brian Ferneyhough and of course Zappa!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Alexander Troup's answer, I'll confirm that [Guitar Pro 6](http://www.guitar-pro.com/) displays the drum track in a "standard" notation (using the [Berklee notation](http://forum.makemusic.com/attach.aspx/12199/berklee_drum_notation_finale.pdf)).

Using this software, you'll be able to open a lot of tabs from the Internet (more or less accurate), you can find them on a lot of websites, like on [Ultimate-Guitar](http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/).
If you don't want to buy a software, you can check out [Songsterr](http://www.songsterr.com/), which is more or less an online Guitar Pro player, the tabs they use are from Internet, so they are not always accurate, but it's often a good start.

Arobas Music, the editor of GP, also have a website where they sell accurate tabs (they are not as accurate as they claim, but they're pretty good) : [MySongBook](http://www.mysongbook.com/), but today there are not a lot of songs.

Answer (score 2):

I play in two bands and we continualy struggle to get sheet music for drums that is acurate and technicaly correct. Agree Guitar Pro is awsome but expensive and some (not many) of the sheets are badly put together for drums.
Our sucsesses have been from two sources Amazon in the sheet music section but can be expensive most books only give  8 or 9 sheets and you probably only need 2 or 3. The other area is [Drumscore.com](http://www.drumscore.com/)
we have had great experiences here and the guy who owns it has been vey helpful to our drummers and offers great advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try SheetMusicPlus or Musescore. They both have vast amounts of sheet music available, for many different instruments.